# Semi-numeric or analytic Hessian for DFT (GAMESS)

Tags: computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I'm trying to understand what parameter in the `$FORCE` group is better to use in computing vibrational frequencies (`NVIB=2`) of compounds after optimization. I'm using GAMESS Aug'16 on Ubuntu 14/16.04.

Initially, three separate methods for both gas and water (PCM) are used to optimize. Later, higher levels of theory are used.

- B3LYP/6-31+G*
- ωB97X-D/6-31+G*
- PBE0 (PBE1PBE)/6-31+G*

Of course, analytic is the default for B3LYP and PBE0, but for ωB97X-D, seminum must be used, from what I've found the hard way. Is it reasonable to use `ANALYTIC` for the former two and `SEMINUM` for the latter or should I use `SEMINUM` across the board to avoid misconstrued results? I'm not seeing a very large difference in only phenol but a difference is noticeable. Considering my target compounds are much larger than a single ring, they may become more noticeable.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: I think, yes, you should use `SEMINUM` for all your calculations.

Comment: Well, those are different functionals, result will be different anyways. What would be the reason for using it for every fnctional?

I would first try if the results are actually different between analytical and semi-numeric.

Comment: Another good resource for GAMESS (US) is the google group for GAMESS